# Windows 8 tablet application

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-8.1, tablet-pc

I am new to Windows 8 apps development and I want to develop a small hello work application using WPF. My target platform is Windows 8 surface pro 2 tablet. After searching/reading in net, many suggested that we need to develop in Windows 8.1 OS platform using 8.1 SDK, is my understanding correct?

Please suggest!

Comment: You should be able to do everything you need using [VS2013 express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) If you are wanting to create store applications you will need VS2013 Express for Windows

Answer (score 1):

A Surface Pro 2 tablet can run most regular Windows software since it is not limited to only showing metro apps like RT tablets are. That means that if you build a small "Hello World" WPF application it will work on any PRO tablet and most currently supported Windows platforms such as Windows 7 and Windows 8 on PC.

But perhaps the people you were talking too suggested that you build a Windows 8 app instead of a WPF application? That could come with some benefits such as your application being able to run on cheaper hardware (RT tabs costs much less then PRO tabs).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a good app-developer whether it is Windows/Android/IOS then you have to have all the right tools with you. So , In case of Windows , this platform is changing quite rapidly so you have catch up with the latest. first follow these links [**Link1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/apps/br229512.aspx)  and [**Link2**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/) and for getting a good understanding this [**LINK**](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-8-1-developer-training-geek-edition-jump-start) is quite good though.
Also try to explore builds videos on [**Channel9**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Windows). After some exploration you will get your answer.

Right now you need VS2013 and A PC :) with configration that can support VS2013 and Windows 8/Windows 8.1 OS. 
Any other help just let me know.

cheers :)